# Using getScrollTop to work with :Hover elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure how exactly to make it so that the navbox is opaque after scrolling until hovered over, I would also like to incorporate CSS3 Transitions into this.

This is the working code without hover:

```
  <Script>
window.onload = function() {

  function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined' ) {
      // Most browsers
      return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (d.clientHeight) {
      // IE in standards mode
      return d.scrollTop;
    }

    // IE in quirks mode
    return document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById('navbox'),
        scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 1) {
      box.style.top = "0px";
      box.style.opacity = "1";
    }
    else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 0) + "px";
      box.style.opacity = "0.25";
    }
  };
};
</script>
```

I've tried adding  `var hoverbox = document.getElementById('navbox:Hover'),` and then using opacity in that fashion below with:

```
if (scroll <= 1) {
  box.style.top = "0px";
  box.style.opacity = "1";
  navbox.style.opacity = "1";
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any advice on how to make the hover transition work with JScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it's wrong. With this command `document.getElementById('navbox:Hover')` you are saying to browser, catch the element where your id is equal 'navbox:hover'. You can try use CSS to this

```
<style>
  #navbox{
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 1s;
  }
  #navbox:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>
```

**Note: The transition property don't are avalaible in all browsers.**

**Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera supports the transition property.**

**Safari requires the prefix -webkit-.**

**Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the transition property.**

**Chrome 25, and earlier versions, requires the prefix -webkit-.**

Read more about this in [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and in [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

With JS you can use this way:

```
<script>
  function FadeIn(){
    this.style.opacity = "0.5";
  }
  function FadeOut(){
    this.style.opacity = "1";
  }
  function LoadEvents(){
    var div = document.getElementById("teste");
    div.addEventListener("mouseover", FadeIn, false);
    div.addEventListener("mouseout", FadeOut, false);
  }
</script>
<body onload="LoadEvents()">
```

But, I advise use JQuery, is more easy. For to know more about addEventListener(), read this in [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `navbox:Hover`. There is a method in jquery `mouseover` which can define actions to do after mouse over the element.
Or you can use `addEventListener()` to define the mouseover event. 
Check the documentation on how to use the `mouseover` function.